# Wondering the correct way to embed php in html

Tags: php, html

I wrote code to dynamically create a list of countries for a menu in HTML, and the code works when run as a php file, but when I tried to embed it in an html page, it didn't work.

My code looked something like

```
...

<form action=...>

<?php

include("connect.php");

$ret = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries");

echo "<select id='countries' name='countries'>";

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($ret)){

echo "<option value='{$array['abbrevs']}'>{$array['full']}</option>";

}

echo "</select>";

?>

</form>
```

with this, it output the while loop and php characters, but none of the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the file the `php` extension.

Generally, servers are set up to only run files with the `php` extension through PHP. You can modify this, but it is generally best to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't embed php code in an html file and have it interpreted as PHP.  You should probably just name the file with the above code file.php instead of file.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the code in a .php or .phtml file, depending on your web-server configuration. .html files will be rendered with content-type text/html and therefore will be treated as such, without passing it through mod_php.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a web server will be configured to treat files with a .php extension as PHP files but to treat files with a .html extension as plain HTML.

If you want to change that behavior and make it so files that have a .html extension are treated as PHP, you can use Apache's [`ForceType` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#forcetype) (assuming you're running Apache).  Personally, I don't recommend doing that, but it certainly can be done.